# List elements not updated in c:forEach

Tags: jsf-2, dialog, primefaces, arraylist, foreach

I developing search engine for my database. I have a dialog and I get some inputs from this dialog. There are maximum 5 panels and the panels have selectOneMenus, inputTexts etc.
I can show and hide input lines by pressing `+` and `-` buttons. This is not the problem.

The problem is that none of properties of AdvancedSearch is set.

Browse class has the objects below(setter,and getters are okey):

```
private List<String> advSearchCols = new ArrayList<>();
private List<AdvancedSearch> advSearch = new ArrayList<>();
```

AdvancedSearch class :

```
private String selectedColumn = "",
        search = "",
        logic = "",
        isEqual = "";

private int widgetNum=-1;
```

Setter and getters are written properly and `advSearch` is initialized properly.

```
      <h:form >
        <p:dialog width="800px" height="300px" widgetVar="advSearchWg" 
                  closable="true" draggable="true" minimizable="true" dynamic="true"
                  position="center" closeOnEscape="true" header="Advanced Search" onShow="L0.show()">

            <c:forEach items="#{browse.advSearch}" var="adv">                    
                <p:panel widgetVar="L#{adv.widgetNum}" visible="false" style="height: 50px;border:none;margin:0px 20px 0px 20px" closable="true">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="7">
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{adv.logic}" style="width: 100px;margin-left: 20px" >  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="AND" itemValue="AND" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="OR" itemValue="OR"  />                                                                   
                        </p:selectOneMenu>  
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{adv.isEqual}" style="width: 100px;margin-left: 20px" >  
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="EQUAL" itemValue="equal" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="NOT EQUAL" itemValue="not equal"  />                                                                   
                        </p:selectOneMenu> 
                        <p:inputText value="#{adv.search}" required="true" autocomplete="true" style="width: 100px;margin-left: 20px"/>
                        <h:outputText value="in" style="margin-left: 20px" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{adv.selectedColumn}" style="width: 100px;margin-left: 20px" >  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{browse.advSearchCols}" />  
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <c:if test="#{adv.nextWg() != (browse.advSearch.size() - 1)}">
                            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" oncomplete="L#{adv.nextWg()}.show()" />                                
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="#{adv.widgetNum != 0}">
                            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-minus" oncomplete="L#{adv.widgetNum}.close()"/>
                        </c:if>
                    </h:panelGrid>                        
                </p:panel>                   
            </c:forEach>
            <p:commandButton process="@this" async="true" action="#{browse.advSearcher()}" value="Search" style="margin-left:60px" icon="ui-icon-search" />
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

OUTPUT :

[image]

Why are `logic`, `isEqual`, `search` and `selectedColumn` not updated? Why are elements of list not updated?

I use Primefaces 3.5RC1.

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" ... />
```

you're not processing all input components in the form. You're only processing the button component itself. Remove that attribute. It defaults to `@form` already.

Further, I recommend to use `<ui:repeat>` and `rendered` attribute instead of `<c:forEach>` and `<c:if>`.

Comment: If i don't use process="@this" , action in the commandButton not fired and also form not submitted.Thus, i did it @this.I solved the problem by adding h:form inside of forEach.Then I wrote javascript code that submits all forms.When i click commandButton i submit all forms.What else can i do?

Comment: As said, use `<ui:repeat>` and `rendered` attribute instead of `<c:forEach>` and `<c:if>`.